# Symbol could not be resolved

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I have a program that tells me "Symbol xxxx could not be resolved" in eclipse C/c++ cdt.

Sample files are below:

**header file: `s.h`:**

```
#ifndef S_H_
#define S_H_

typedef enum {
    MSG_ID_INVALID_TYPE = 0,
    #include "s0.h"
} msg_type;

#endif /* S_H_ */
```

The above file includes the header file shown below:

**header file `s0.h`**

```
MSG_ID_COMMAND1,
MSG_ID_COOMAND2,
```

**The main file `test.c`**

```
/*
 * test.c
 *
 *  Created on: 2012-5-18
 *      Author: js
 */
#include "s.h"

int i = MSG_ID_COMMAND1;

main()
{
    print ("%d",i);
}
```

Eclipse tells me: `Symbol MSG_ID_COMMAND1 could not be resolved`

But the program is ok in vc2008.

Why?

// answer: Seth Carnegie. if we use i =  MSG_ID_INVALID_TYPE, it is  ok.

Comment: does header file  `so.h` have only the following lines  `MSG_ID_COOMAND1,MSG_ID_COOMAND2,` if so i don't think there should be a comma after `MSG_ID_COOMAND2`

Comment: @keety the extra comma is legal.

Comment: @user1402307 Try using `MSG_ID_INVALID_TYPE` to see if that works.

Comment: Does eclipse care that the `#include` doesn't begin in the first column?  An unrelated nit, but `i` should be declared as `msg_type`, not `int`.

Comment: but i should be declared as msg_type, not int. // this is ok.not error here.

Comment: The snippet you created does not compile because `print` does not exist and there are no includes to define it.

Comment: print is my write fault. it is printf.

Comment: this is a real project. the project use some h file to define COMMMAND. and some h file include the COMMAND h file. the project is ok under ARM rvct compile. but we import to eclipse so mang the COMMAND is not resolved.

Comment: Are you using the same compiler and options in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
typedef enum {
    MSG_ID_INVALID_TYPE = 0,
    #include "s0.h"
```

to

```
typedef enum {
    MSG_ID_INVALID_TYPE = 0,
#include "s0.h"
```

Some preprocessors ignore tokens which aren't left-justified. The VS one doesn't, apparently the eclipse one does.

Comment: Is that quirk or a requirement - I've seen lots of `#       if` type things - never run into a pre-processor that needed it though.

Comment: Space between the `#` the token is fine.

Comment: can you sure that the program style is not well support by eclipse, or it is eclipse cdt bug?

Comment: @Dave - I know its ok - is it ever required - never met a compiler that wants it.

Comment: @kangjw I only care about the C99 standard - if the compiler doesnt support it - I dont care what it does.

Comment: but the above program is ok in VC2008 and ARM rvct compile. maybe the style is covered by C99.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you created does not compile because `print` function does not exist and there are no includes to define it

Comment: My point still stands - where are you including <stdio.h> - or does the exact example you show produce the error?

Comment: <stdio.h> include in  inc  path setting in compile setting. or if you want to repeat it, please add the stdio.h in test.c file head.

Comment: Do you include it or not? You either do it or not.